# NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder

Tags: slf4j, log4j

Have added jar's in Tomcat/lib [Tomcat 7]

```
log4j-1.2.15.jar,
log4j-api-2.0-alpha2.jar,
log4j-jcl-2.0-alpha2.jar,
logback-classic-1.1.7.jar,
log4j12-api-2.0-alpha2.jar,
log4j-core-2.0-alpha2.jar,
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar,
logback-core-1.1.7.jar

slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar,
slf4j-jcl-1.7.21.jar,
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar,
slf4j-nop-1.7.21.jar
slf4j-ext-1.7.21.jar,
slf4j-jdk14-1.7.21.jar,
slf4j-migrator-1.7.21.jar,
slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar
```

Getting error & causing deployment failure

Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:121)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:268)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:241)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.AbstractRestServlet.<clinit>(AbstractRestServlet.java:34)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1894)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1146)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5349)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5641)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:607)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:844)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:823)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:325)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
```

Not sure what am I missing. Can any one share some light how to rectify the error.

Regards

Comment: It worked for me. I used 1.7.25 as the version.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error and I believe my solution addressed it. I am using Maven so I added a dependency in my POM file rather than explicitly add the .jar file to the build path.

Here's the dependency(the most recent version is listed at the top of the link below. In my case it was 1.7.24, so if you can subsitute the most recent version for "${slf4j-version}":

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api

Let me know if that works out for you.